# How do I obtain longer iOS console logs out of Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, logging, console

I'm trying to provide console logs to apple to illustrate what happens when I experience a certain error on an iPad (not related to application crash logs, need console logs). The error occurs on production iPads that we have in the field, but the problem we have is by the time I get hold of them, the 'console log' buffer no longer shows in XCode >> Devices >> Console Log screen (arrow button).

Whenever I plug an iPad into the system, I can only access the last hour worth of console log entries. I need the last 24-48 hours worth, at least.

Is there a setting that can be changed that records the console log for a longer time? Is it already recorded for a longer time? Is there a different tool I can use to access console logs for an extended period?

Any assistance or pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I never did, unfortunately :(